# OPs that Throw the Baby Out with the Bathwater

Tags: discussion, answers, abandoned-questions

Is this a problem or a blessing?

A few times around SO, I've seen a good answer that didn't quite solve the OP's problem but did get them 90% of the way there. The correct solution has been a very small, and sometimes frankly bloody obvious, leap away from the posted answer ...

However, the OP comments on the answer saying the solution didn't work and either announces they're abandoning the question, or are waiting for a better answer. Sometimes they don't comment on what the result was from applying the answer as written, which is very unhelpful. Basically, the OP throws the baby out with the bathwater - rejecting the solution because it didn't work on first attempt.

From a visitor's point of view, I could (and have) just edited the answer to provide the missing link, and comment that the answer has been updated - or the original answerer could do the same; but it frustrates me that the OP didn't make the effort to adapt the answer to their exact situation, and then comment on that answer with the update. (I have seen that done a number of times, and applaud the OPs for doing so).

Sometimes I think questions are asked by other users - who even reference another question/answer - because they can't make the simple adaptation from an answer.

Is this a problem that some users are unable to adapt an answer to their own specific problem, or is it a blessing because we're more likely to get better quality answers?

Comment: If the answer doesn't solve the problem why should they accept the answer? Just because you where able to put in the missing parts doesn't mean that the op was able to see what was missing and figure it out.

Comment: The ease of asking a question at SO is not always a good match with the need to ask it.  Best to keep focusing on posting an answer for the next several hundreds of programmers that are going to google it some day.  The OP is just one.

Comment: "it frustrates me that the OP didn't make the effort to _________" This is a frequent hot topic on Meta. Don't get frustrated; remember that for every poster who asks a question, there may be tens, hundreds, or even thousands of people who visit the page in the future, many of whom *will* be able to fill in that gap.

Comment: I got down voted the other day for providing the (only) correct solution; problem was it couldn't be auto-generated by the OPs client. At some point you're just not going to rescue everyone and it's simply not worth worrying about...

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Some people really want cooked fish flying directly into their mouth, but for heaven's sake without any fishbones.
Those guys are mostly not salvageable short of a major miracle.

Of course, it happens that someone just cannot see the woods for trees, or has a bad day.
Happens to everyone, even (or especially) me.

It's also possible that this - in our eyes so obvious and small step - is quite a lot of a bigger leap than we recognize, which means the answer should be extended.
In which case the question is, where should one stop?
After programming their enterprise server from the ground up to their vague and oft-revised specification?

All in all, it's a mixed bag, some of it smelly like yesteryear's rotten fish, some of it roses.

Comment: I [recently](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25333828/how-to-manipulate-class-attributes-using-variables) had an OP complain that I shouldn't have voted to close his question as a duplicate, because the duplicate used different variable names than he was using.