# Can questions that "boil down" to another question be closed as duplicates?

Tags: discussion, duplicate-questions

I have often found questions which are worded quite differently, but nevertheless boil down to a more general question.

For example, recently I found a question asking how to load a Qt widget plugin into an application. The author off-handedly mentions the plugin's Project is compiled as 32-bit while the application's Project is compiled as 64-bit.

Since this boils down to loading a 32-bit DLL into a 64-bit application, I marked it as duplicate of [Load 32bit DLL library in 64bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32bit-dll-library-in-64bit-application). The author however protested, saying his question is not like that at all.

While I understand where he's coming from, and I agree his question is not at all similar at first glance, it's mainly because the author himself might not have realised that Qt plugins are DLL files. After taking this (perhaps non-obvious) step, the connection becomes clear.

So my question is, how "exact" do the questions need to be? Can "Question X boils down to the more general question Y" be a sufficient reason to close as a duplicate?

Comment: this question boils down to a duplicate of many others :)

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271494/ops-that-throw-the-baby-out-with-the-bathwater/271495#271495

Comment: I had the same story at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30117982/preprocessor-directives-in-c-macros-using-line/30118222) ^0^

Comment: What if the duplicate is excellently worded and easy to find, and the original question is crap and nobody can find it.

Comment: @hardmath I intentionally didn't link to it to avoid the meta-effect.

Comment: Very well, but what you've done is create "a bubble effect" in which you dictate the facts and receive feedback that is biased by your filtering.  I have removed my linking.

Comment: @SandyGood - If the good question also has good answers, mark the poor question as a duplicate of the good one. If the good question does not have answers but the poor question does, edit the question to make it good and mark the other question as the duplicate.  The goal is to help people find answers and good content.

Comment: I'd like to see stackoverflow implement something like multiple possible wordings of a question for the search.

Comment: @SandyGood: That's what the duplicate question feature does. Instead of using an algorithm for generating multiple possible wording it uses users to ask multiple possible wordings and other users to point out that all those wordings have the same answer

Comment: @SandyGood: Therefore, in my opinion, it's much more important for duplicates to point to the best ANSWER instead of the best question.

Comment: Definitely yes. I would add a small caveat. I have come across cases where two different questions can be answered by the same answer. But the questions don't seem like they are duplicates.

Comment: The meta effect cannot be avoided :P http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30568138/import-custom-qwidget-into-qt-designer

Answer (score 61, accepted):

IMO, not only can they, but they should. The problem is that many people expect answers custom-tailored to their very specific question, often because they do not have enough knowledge/won't invest the effort to realize that the dupe applies to their situation as well.

Again, in my opinion, we really shouldn't be catering to the this kind of individual because they cannot be numbered among 'enthusiast and professional programmers'.

Comment: I agree but with a tiny remark: figuring out the core of your question can be very hard. In fact, in many cases once you get to the core, you know the answer. Due to the fact that a closed question remains 'find-able' and provides a link to the answer, people having the same (high level) issue will be able to get to the core. I do not consider people who can't get to the core unworthy of the 'enthusiast and professional programmer' label. Sometimes it is hard to get there.

Comment: In cases where the connection is not quickly obvious I would think that an explanation of how question A boils down to question B would be an appropriate answer but that the question itself would not necessarily end up being a duplicate.  Having seemingly unrelated questions marked as duplicate with explanations only buried deep in comments seems less useful to future users than having the explanation in an accepted answer.

Comment: @altendky: then I would suggest to leave an answer detailing in what way it's a duplicate *and* still close it as a duplicate.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd: The issue isn't "can or can't get to the core", the issue is whether they are even willing to try.

Comment: @BenVoigt: I find "willingness to try" hard to assess. Someone who is stuck and willing to try should be able to find a question of someone who was as stuck as he was, be redirected to the core issue and get an answer. I am simply advocating multiple entry points to the same solution. What is obvious for some to try might not be for the one stuck in the mud. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BQ4yd2W50No

Comment: Some posters broadcast their level of willingness loud and clear. Haven't you ever seen the comment that, if you knew anything about programming you would just give them working code, and your vote to close is a clear sign that you don't understand their issue? Some people are unwilling to do even the most basic of adaptation to make an explanation fit their particular homework.

Comment: @Jeroen Vannevel: Then you'll get people either 1) downvoting and flagging the answer stating it should never have been posted, or 2) voting to reopen the question if the answer sufficiently distinguishes it from the linked question.

Comment: @ErnodeWeerd I would agree, many time I have typed a question into stack overflow, and by the time I finished my question I figured out what I was really after and didn't even need the post.

Answer (score 12):

When OP's question is not a programming question but actually a debugging question, I'm greatly in favor of closing as a duplicate of a canonical question explaining the problem properly using that question and its answers, so OP can go analyze the problem and *then*, after finding the original issue, ask a question about their code - if that's even required anymore at that point, as debugging will usually give you that "aha-erlebnis" you need to find the actual issue.

This is because the question usually *can't* be answered without a lot of forth-and-back in comments and answers, so people uselessly spend effort helping someone debug by hand-holding where the debugging steps for that specific problem are spelled out in another Q&A pair altogether. Only when OP finds their original issue, they have a "valid" question, so go ahead and close it.

OP can then discuss in comments why they think it *isn't* a duplicate and explain what steps they have performed to troubleshoot the issue.

See also my post in [Does a well explained question nullify a "no research effort" downvote?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291081/does-a-well-explained-question-nullify-a-no-research-effort-downvote/291268#291268) that touches this subject.

For example in the C# / .NET tags, there's those questions that aren't usually answerable from the question itself, but that require more debugging from OP:

- "Why do I get a NullReferenceException?" - [What is a NullReferenceException, and how do I fix it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)
- "Why does my site give a '500 internal server error'?" - [How to find the underlying cause for an HTTP 500 - Internal server error in IIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385714/deploying-website-500-internal-server-error)
- "Why does my 32-bit assembly not load in a 64-bit process?" - ["An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" even when the platforms are the same](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2023766/an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-even-when-the-p), [I get a "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" error on a SQL Server replication project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-o), [Could not load file or assembly ... An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format (System.BadImageFormatException)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a)

Close as dupe, let OP do the debugging.

---

Of course when the cause isn't that obvious, you could post an answer instead, but *please* don't copy or rewrite explanations and troubleshooting hints from existing answers:

> Your foo bars the qux because of baz. See the explanation of this and how to solve this in http://link-to-other-question.
>
> [optional (pseudo) code block showing how to do so for OP's case specifically.]

Answer (score 11):

My preference on these is a hybrid.  Post an answer that explains the DLL issue, and then close as dupe.  This is particularly useful because the dup hangs about (for searching purposes) - so when someone else finds the question, they not only get the duplicate link, but also a short answer that explains why it's relevant (if it's not immediately so).

A comment can be used for this purpose as well, and for smaller differences should be, but I like using a real answer when it's sufficiently complex that it's important it stays around (and when it could be seen as an answer legitimately).

In this case, I'd put something like

> Your issue here is that a QT Plugin is really a DLL.  Because of this, it must follow the rules of DLLs as linked in the duplicate question.

That probably would be fine as a comment, or as an answer - I'd be okay with either.  I wouldn't reiterate the duplicate's information there; the link to the duplicate is sufficient.  (I also wouldn't put the link to the duplicate in the answer - that's what close-as-dup is for.)

Comment: Any link will turn up in the Linked section of **both** questions, so in a sense, writing an answer or simply mentioning the connection will still cover you, albeit less conspicuously. I've learned to check the Linked section when researching.

Comment: Great answer, and far preferable to the high scoring answer in my opinion, as the solution tries to help everyone rather than be overly elitist.

Comment: Depending on circumstances, I would prefer a comment to an answer, but I guess that's a matter of taste.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say it depends on whether the question "boils down" to another because of the fact that is essentially *is* the other question with some other irrelevant information around it, or whether it boils down to it via some series of inferences that the asker may not have had the information to make.

As an example:

> Q1: Why can't I assign a `List<string>` to a `List<object>`?
>
> Q2: Why can't I assign a list of a derived type to a list of a base type?
>
> A2: Because variance.

This is a reasonable duplicate - the original question is a subset of the problem covered by the second question and `A2` is a valid direct answer to `Q1`.

On the other hand:

> Q1: How can I decouple these two classes?
>
> Q2: How do I implement an interface in C#?
>
> A2: Like this: `class Foo : IBar`

Q1 -> A2 here is a non-sequitur; it doesn't directly answer the question without an intermediary step; explaining the concept of an interface (a slightly awkward example but you get the gist).

So, in essence, if question 1 and question 2 are such that any possible answer to question 2 is necessarily a direct and appropriate answer to question 1, by all means, close it as a duplicate.

If I ask a question and you close my question as a duplicate of another, but I have to go off and learn a bunch of extra stuff before I even understand the context of the other question (and this happens more than you'd think), you've done something wrong.

Answer (score -1):

In my opinion, this isn't really a duplicate question; it's a unique question with a follow-up question that already has an answer. Without being able to reference the original post, it sounds like the question is something along the lines of:

"Why won't my Qt widget plugin load?"

The answer is: "It isn't working because you haven't followed the correct steps to load the 32bit DLL. See [Load 32bit DLL library in 64bit application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2265023/load-32bit-dll-library-in-64bit-application)."

I would have the asker edit the question (and possibly title) so that it contains the exact error and asks for the reason of the error; then answer with an explanation of the error.

Answer (score -3):

Although your example is a borderline case, I don't think such a question should be closed. If you have to know the answer in order to know the right search keywords, then this transition (from the actual question to "what the question boils down to") is worth an answer by itself and so, the question is also not a duplicate of the other (although you certainly should link to it instead of repeating all the information that is already provided there).

In my opinion, it's pretty similar to the reason why you don't answer a question by just saying "You can find the answer in the standard". Instead, you give

1. the specific part that is relevant to the question
2. additional information about how and why that part applies to the concrete question